can we create paypal payout using MerchantIdbyPaypal
I am working on seller onboarding through partner referral. I got paypal merchant Id in return url can i directly create payout using this id. if not then what step do i need to take to get the email of that merchant so that i can create payouts.
I tried to get account id by using this paypal endpoint

f"{settings.PAYPAL_BASE_URL}/v2/customer/partners/merchant-integrations/{merchant_id}


The merchant ID should be an account ID. So, just create the payout with it.

no we can create payout with payer id not merchant id

They are the same thing.

no they are not

Yes, they are .
